# Selenium WebDriver : AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'ChromeOptions'

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I made a successfull unit test with Selenium WebDriver python. This latter downloads a file in a custom location that I've defined, assert the file had been correctly downloded and delete it.
Here is its code :

```
import os
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() ;
prefs = {"download.default_directory" : "C:\\Users\\AminataWillane\\Desktop\\selenium_download"}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs);
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./chromedriver',chrome_options=options)

driver.get('https://www.browserstack.com/test-on-the-right-mobile-devices');
gotit= driver.find_element(By.ID,'accept-cookie-notification');
gotit.click();
downloadcsv= driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.icon-csv')
downloadcsv.click();
time.sleep(10)

#check file
try:
  print('try started')
  if os.path.isfile('C:\\Users\\AminataWillane\\Desktop\\selenium_download\\BrowserStack - List of devices to test on.csv'):
     print("File download is completed and the file will be deleted")
     time.sleep(5)
     os.remove("C:\\Users\\AminataWillane\\Desktop\\selenium_download\\BrowserStack - List of devices to test on.csv")
     print("File had been removed successfully")
except FileNotFoundError as er:
  print("File Not Found !")
```

Then once I tried out the same logic while implementing Page Object Model, it isn't working :
here is the related code :

```
import os
import time
from seleniumpagefactory.Pagefactory import PageFactory
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from test.test_download import options

class QA_download_me(PageFactory):
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver
        options = driver.ChromeOptions();

        prefs = {"download.default_directory": "C:\\Users\\AminataWillane\\Desktop\\selenium_download"}

        options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs);
        driver.Chrome(executable_path='./chromedriver', chrome_options=options)

    locators = {
        "documentation": ('ID', 'NavLinkDocumentation'),
        "sdk": ('ID', 'NavLinkDocumentation1'),
        "download_btn": ('XPATH', '//*[@id="server-root"]/div/div/main/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/a[1]'),
    }

    def download_me(self):
        # create a service
        self.documentation.click_button()
        time.sleep(5)
        self.sdk.click_button()
        time.sleep(5)
        self.download_btn.click_button()
        time.sleep(10)
        try:
            print('try started')
            if os.path.isfile(
                    'C:\\Users\\AminataWillane\\Desktop\\selenium_download\\MyriadSDK-latest.tgz'):
                print("File download is completed and the file will be deleted")
                time.sleep(5)
                os.remove(
                    "C:\\Users\\AminataWillane\\Desktop\\selenium_download\\MyriadSDK-latest.tgz")
                print("File had been removed successfully")

        except FileNotFoundError as er:
            print("File Not Found !")
```

Here is the error I've got :

```
ERROR: test_download_me (test.test_book_2.TestLoginTwo)
    down= QA_download_me(self.driver)
  File "C:\Users\AminataWillane\PycharmProjects\myProj\src\pages\download_me.py", line 15, in __init__
    options = driver.ChromeOptions();
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'ChromeOptions'
```

Answer (score 0):

in the second code snipper, when ur calling ChromeOptions() from driver, driver is only self.driver and hasn't yet been identified as selenium.webdriver.

try adding to imports:

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

and then say:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
```

this also goes for when you instantiate your webdriver later (remove self.driver = driver from beginning of code):

```
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(...)
```